# jQuery UI - toggle slide appears from top right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am using the jQuery UI library to try and create a 'slide in menu' like is found on apps and many other mobile websites. I am using using the toggle function to allow the user to show and hide it etc. It is all working fine except for one thing I'm not keen on and that is how it appears from the top right corner of the screen. I am assuming this might be affected by the standard jQuery origin settings or something? If anyone could guide me that would be fantastic, I am just looking for it to slide in horizontally. Here is the code I am using as of now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sidebar").hide();

    $('#sidebar-trigger').click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle("slide");
    });

});
```

Comment: could you provide the minimal html too

Comment: @depperm I have sorted it now... thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found that the direction property did just what I needed. Sorry for wasting time. Solution:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sidebar").hide();

    $('#sidebar-trigger').click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle('slide', { direction: 'right'}, 500);
    });

});
```